# How to import lib.sort in Python

Tags: python, youtube, live-streaming

I am trying to run a script that has the line:

```
import lib.sort as sort
```

When I try to run it I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.sort'
```

So then I did:

```
import lib
```

but then when I tried to use `lib.sort` I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'sort'
```

Can someone point out my presumably basic mistake?

Answer (score 0):

`lib` module in Python does not have `sort` method. Do you want to sort the elements? Can you explain what functionality you need?

Answer (score 0):

[@user1551817]
Try: pip install lib
Then, run dir(lib) to check if 'sort' function is available.

As far as I tried, lib doesnt have sort method.